# Python, sorting my list from its original form

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have been searching but haven't found any thread that matches what I'm looking for. What I'm trying to do, is sorting a list from 3 different options, Chronological(The original list), Alphabetical and Reversed sorting.
All of them, I have figured out, for example here is my list:

```
movies = ["Star Wars", "Hamilton", "Fight club", "Beck", "Wallander"]
```

And here's my code:

```
def print_movies():
    global movies
    j = 0
    while j < 1:
        print("Hur vill du skriva ut filmerna?")
        print("1. Kronologisk\n2. Alfabetisk stigande\n3. Alfabetisk fallande")
        choice = input()
        if int(choice) == 1:    
            print("Filmer i samlingen just nu:\n")
            for i in movies:
                print(i)
                j = j+1
        elif int(choice) == 2:
            print("Filmer i samlingen just nu:\n")
            movies.sort()
            for i in movies:
                print(i)
                j = j+1
        elif int(choice) == 3:
            print("Filmer i samlingen just nu:\n")
            movies.sort(reverse=True)
            for p in movies:
                print(p)
                j = j+1
        else:
            print("Not a valid option, try again")
```

The sorting and everything works fine, but when I for example press: 2, sort in Alphabetical, it prints out Alphabetical, and when I press: 1 the next time, it doesn't go back to Chronological.
So the option 2 and 3 works fine, it can sort from highest Alphabetical character to reversed sorting but it wont go back to its original list form, and by that I mean:

```
["Star Wars", "Hamilton", "Fight club", "Beck", "Wallander"]
```

When I press: 1, its still sorted in either option 2 or 3 of which I entered before.

Would really appreciate the help here.
Thanks!

Comment: So how do you know they are in chronological order? You told Python to sort the list, so the original order is *gone*. If you need the original order, either keep a copy of the list that is never sorted, or add information to your data to sort on chronologically.

Comment: Sorry for my english, by chronological order i mean the order where it was in the first list. The original order from the list.

Comment: That's because you're sorting `in place`. That is, modifying the original list. For chronological you want to keep the original order. So, instead of `movies.sort` , do `new_movies = sorted(movies)` for options 2 and 3. Option 1 can still display from movies itself.

Comment: `sort` modified list in place. You can make a copy of the original list. When you need the "chronological"  ones, you could just return that copied list.

Comment: Why do you have `global movies`? This isn't related to what you're asking, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't do anything in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`movies.sort()` modifies the list. so you will lose your original ordering.

Try `for m in sorted(movies):` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a copy of your list, because `movies.sort()`, modifies to original list.

```
copyMovies = movies[:]
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> movies = ["Star Wars", "Hamilton", "Fight club", "Beck", "Wallander"]
>>> copyMovies = movies[:]
>>> movies.sort()
>>> movies
['Beck', 'Fight club', 'Hamilton', 'Star Wars', 'Wallander']
>>> copyMovies
['Star Wars', 'Hamilton', 'Fight club', 'Beck', 'Wallander']
>>>
```